# Convert Lambda into Java Function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have 2 questions.

1.

I want to convert Lambda into a Java function, but do not know how to do it.

```
//GET Method For REST Application
public Topic getTopics(String id){
    return topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
}
```

The `topics` is a list defined as:

```
private List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<Topic>(
    Arrays.asList(
        new Topic("1","Spring Framework","Spring")
    )
);
```

Class `Topic` is defined as:

```
public class Topic {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String description;

    public Topic() {}

    public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

2.

I have 1 more question regarding the code. It is about filter function. Why is it that only `t` can be used as predicate? Hovering over t gives me this definition

`Topic t - project_path.getTopics(...).() -> {...} Predicate.test(Topic)`

Comment: `t` is simply a variable you give for each instance in the topic stream. You can change `t -> t.getId().equals(id)` into `foo -> foo.getId().equals(id)` if you want to.

Comment: Always try to ask one question per post.

Comment: Thanks...I will keep in mind next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to learn more about JAVA 8 streams. Anyhow here is answer to your questions:

```
public Topic getTopics(String id) {
    return topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
}
```

is same as

```
public Topic getTopics(String id) {
     for (Topic curTopic:topics) {
          if (curTopic.getId().equals(id)) return curTopic;
     }
     return null;
}
```

Secondly, for your second question, you can use anything as formal parameter, so below will also work fine (see also [Syntax of Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax)):

```
public Topic getTopics(String id) {
    return topics.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
}
```

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: Not *exactly* same as, given that [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) throws `NoSuchElementException` if nothing is found.

Comment: @Andreas The motive here is to give basic idea. All boundary scenarios can be amended as and when required.

Answer (score 3):

That lambda in your filter combinator can be extracted into a variable (predicate):

```
Predicate<Topic> hasSameId = topic -> id.equals(topic.getId());
```

or into a *method*:

```
Boolean hasSameId(Topic topic) {
    return id.equals(topic.getId());
}
```

In either case it would be good practice though to pass `id` along by currying either version:

```
Function<String, Predicate<Topic>> hasSameId = id -> topic -> id.equals(topic.getId());
```

It can then be used like this:

```
topics.stream().filter(hasSameId.apply(id)).findFirst();
```